# get json from Observable.forkjoin

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

```
Observable.forkJoin(
  this.ids.map(
    i => this.http.get('api_url' + i) //return a json for each url
      .map(res=> res.json())
  )).subscribe(res=> this.data = res.data)
```

it prompt `[ts] Property 'data' does not exist on type 'any[]'.` so how can I get json from the forkjoin response?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ForkJoin will return array of response , you will need to loop through array to get data of each request.

```
    this.data = [];
Observable.forkJoin( this.ids.map( i => this.http.get('api_url' + i) //return a json for each url .map(res=> res.json()) )).subscribe(aRes=> {
    aRes.forEach((res) =>  this.data.push( res.data));
});
```